# How to translate a BPMN2 model into other languages?

Tags: internationalization, bpmn

I need to build a translator for BPMN2 models, a translator for other languages not model types (internationalization).

My question, is there a standard way to translate a BPMN model?
I did not find anything in the specification (did not read the whole 540 pages though, maybe missed the right spot).

Having the following element I would like to translate the "name" of the task and the "documentation".
Is there a standard way to add the translated "name" and "documentation" to the model or should I use separated properties file?

```
<bpmn2:userTask id="UserTask_1" name="Simple User Task">
  <bpmn2:documentation id="Documentation_1">This is a Documentation </bpmn2:documentation>
  <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_1</bpmn2:incoming>
  <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_2</bpmn2:outgoing>
</bpmn2:userTask>
```

This leads to the next question is there some information on what should be translated of a BPMN model, is it only the "name" and "documentation"?

Comment: I'd first ask my vendor of the bpmn tool for the best practices and for some tool support. In case of no good news, I'd concentrate on the right choice of the data exchange formats acceptable by the translation office (they probably won't work with xml files) and on setting up the translation and manual testing process loops. The more of it you can automatize the better, but the exact algorithm for extracting/injecting the translation dictionary from/to bpmn-xml files is in my opinion the least problem in the whole chain as you can add new xpath keys to your mapping tool anytime

Comment: According to your comment there is no standard way on translating a model? Is that a fact? I thought there might be some XML subelement of bpmn2:userTask and bpmn2:documentation.

Comment: I don't know if there's a standard way. I'm not saying there is not. I'm saying I'd ask the tool vendor (author of the `bpmn` editing tool) as they work with the format already and there even may be a built-in support (like in [SAP Process Composer](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/f9/3786c2167d40b49ad920d59c0481f6/content.htm)). And I'm also saying that knowing where exactly in the `xml` files are the language-specific texts encoded is (the simpler) part of the problem. I'm not saying I know the answer. I'm saying what I'd do wearing your shoes. Sorry if not helping

Comment: Have you tried Atlas Transformation Language?

Comment: Right now I have all translated labels in a properties files `elementId=label`, using the according properties file I then manipulated the bpmn model for the language. This works well so I don't need ATL.